# Помогите с заданием js

Tags: javascript

Напишите js скрипт, который распарсит URL-адрес, указанный в формате: `[протокол]: // [сервер] / [ресурс]`, и извлекает из него `[протокол]`, `[сервер]` и`[ресурс]` elements - вернуть элементы в объект JSON.
Например, из URL http: // [www.devbg.org](http://www.devbg.org) / forum / index.php следует извлечь следующую информацию:

```
 {
        protocol: "http",
        server: "www.devbg.org",
        resource: "/forum/index.php"
    }
```

Очевидно, что нужно использовать регулярные выражения, тк json передает строку с текстом. Но вот как реализовать мне совсем непонятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никаких регулярок не нужно. Нужно использовать либо свойства объекта `location`

```js
let urlParts = {
    protocol: location.protocol,
    server: location.hostname,
    resource: location.pathname
}

console.log(urlParts);
```

---

Либо **[URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL)**

```js
let url = new URL('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255469/');
let urlParts =  {
    protocol: url.protocol,
    server: url.host,
    resource: url.pathname
}

console.log(urlParts);
```

Comment: А где идет возврат элементов в объект?
Или я совсем не поняла задание?(

Comment: @AliaTempora так вот же итоговый объект: `urlParts`